# Firefox: dconf-Warning When opening Firefox from the Command Line

Tags: command-line, permissions, firefox

I am attempting to write a simple python script which opens multiple Firefox tabs via the command line. I call `os.system(firefox "destination")` multiple times, where "destination" is either a website or file (jpg,png) that I'm trying to open. However, instead of opening each link in the same window, with a tab for each link, it opens each link in its own separate window, one at a time, and spits out the following:

```
(/usr/lib/firefox/firefox/22821): dconf-WARNING **: 14:44:26.260: Unable to open /var/lib/snapd/desktop/dconf/profile/user: Permission denied
```

I've searched up and down for info on this, and haven't come up with anything.

If I already have an instance of Firefox running, this warning doesn't come up, and everything works as intended. It's just when I try to run it without Firefox already running that this warning appears.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Not sure what you are doing, but: 1. `os.system(firefox "destination")` is simply incorrect syntax and will not do what you describe it does. Please edit. 2. Please, Please don't use `os.system` anymore. It has been deprecated for ages.

Comment: here is [the associated bugzilla page](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1410879)

Answer (score 1):

I am receiving a similar error yet I have figured out for me its tied to one of my firefox addons attempting to connect yet being blocked due to multi factor authentication. I would recommend starting firefox in safe mode (firefox -safe-mode askubuntu.com) and see if there is a issue with any extension or addon.